# Mac terminal cannot not execute .bash_profile

Tags: bash, terminal

Executing `. .bash_profile` (or `source ~/.bash_profile`) doesn't seem to do anything. (.bash_profile below; I don't see the echo "bash profile end" in the terminal). However, if I copy-paste lines from .bash_profile, they work.

I'm running an interactive login shell, have tried restarting but now am at a loss to understand `. .bash_profile` doesn't return anything. (additionally, when I open a new terminal, .bash_profile isn't sourced, but it was a couple of hours ago). Any help would be most appreciated.

Mac OS Sierra. SHELL: `/bin/bash/`
PATH: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin`

```
# Colors and styles
# export PS1="\[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\]\h:\[\033[33;1m\]\w\[\033[m\]\$ "
export CLICOLOR=1 
export LSCOLORS=ExFxBxDxCxegedabagacad 
alias ls='ls -GFh'
# -G == colorize output, -h size human readable, -F {/ after directory, * after executable, @ after symlink}

# Move homebrew's usr/local/bin ahead of /usr/bin
# export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH

# Add homebrew directory
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH

# virtualenvwrapper
export WORKON_HOME=~/.envs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/bin/python3
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV_ARGS='--no-site-packages'
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

echo "bash profile end"
```

Comment: What are the permissions on .bash_profile?

Comment: they were 644, I've just tried 777 and that didn't help either

Comment: Is your .bashrc sourcing your .bash_profile?  Iirc the mac terminal doesn't start as a login shell but I forget the rule about which is sourced automatically when as I'm sourcing my .bash_profile under Linux. I recall doing the same when I ran OS X.

Comment: I don't seem to have a .bashrc, so no.

Comment: Try creating one and have it source your .bash_profile. If the .bashrc is missing then bash will use the system's copy (/etc/bashrc).

Comment: The issue is really why source .bash_profile doesn't show the "bash profile end" string

Comment: Try this command, `. $HOME/.bash_profile`

Comment: No luck. I think the issue is with the .bash_profile itself...

Comment: In your interactive shell, run `ps $$; echo $-; set -x; . ~/.bash_profile` and post the resulting output.